# 2010 Outlook settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, display-settings

Every morning when I open Outlook my mail options are reset, specificially my signnature fonts AND (the most irritating) in Advanced View Settings: Messages under "Group By" the "automatically group according to arrangement" keeps getting checked. How can I "lock" my settings?

Comment: Do you also get that you have to setup your email account, even though it optionally may setup itself? If so, it might be a profile issue.

Comment: Is this computer on a network domain where the administrator may have a group policy set on Exchange?